# select top 10 row with status = 'A'

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to select top 10 data from a table, where the status = 'A'.

So for example, if the 7th row's status = 'D', i want to SKIP that row. The result from the select query should be : `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the data in a `where` clause

if you wan to select top 10 results, use `limit` in SQLite.

```
select your_column
from your_table
where status = 'A'
order by your_column asc
limit 10
```

That of course makes only sense if you order the data in some way. Otherwise selecting top results would return unpredictable data because a DB does not have a default order in which the data will be presented.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select * from tablename where columnname='A' order by columnname asc limit 10
```